# Determine the maximum error bound on the given interval

Tags: taylor-expansion, upper-lower-bounds

Find the $5th$ degree Maclaurin polynomial of $f(x) = \text{cos}x$. Then, derive an upper bound for max$(-\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}) \mid f(x)-\text{P}_5(x)\mid$.

I found $\text{P}_5(x) = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}$. So,

$\mid f(x)-\text{P}_5(x)\mid = \mid\text{cos}x - (1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24})\mid$.

The RHS attains its maximum value on this interval at $x = .5$. Plugging this in yields,

$\mid\text{cos}(.5) - (1-\frac{.5^2}{2}+\frac{.5^4}{24})\mid = 2.1\times 10^{-5}$. Hence the maximum upper bound is $2.1 \times 10^{-5}$.

Is this process correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The error is not bounded above by zero. The origin is not a local or global maximum for the error - it's the minimum instead. There's an absolute value in that definition, after all. [Now corrected]

Your polynomial is also incorrect - that's the wrong $x^4$ term. [Now corrected]

I suspect you're intended to use Taylor's theorem here. The theorem comes with estimates for the error of the series approximation. What does that error estimate from the theorem say in this case?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the polynomial. I must be confused -- isn't the question just asking me to evaluate $\mid f(x)-\text{P}_5(x) \mid$ where it takes its maximum on the given interval, which in turn gives me the upper bound?

Comment: Okay, I edited my answer. Your comment made me realize that I neglected the absolute value when finding the maximum of the function on $-\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$. What do you think now?

Comment: While it is the maximum, how would you justify that? It's a lot of effort - when the actual question is just to find an upper bound, not the absolute best possible bound. There's a reason I mentioned Taylor's theorem. (Oh, and you didn't fix all of the instances of the polynomial)

Comment: I think I understand the idea of what you're saying. As far as Taylor's theorem, do you mean that I should use the "remainder function" $R_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi (x))x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$?

Comment: Yes. Well, that's one form of the remainder.

Comment: Okay, so I have $R_5(x) = \frac{-\text{cos}(\xi (x))x^{6}}{720}$. I know that in this case, $\mid R_5(x)\mid \leq \mid \frac{x^{6}}{720}\mid$. But now it's not clear to me what to do.

Comment: Can I now just reason that $\frac{x^{6}}{720}$ has its maximum on the given interval at $x = \frac{1}{2}$ and plug that in? And then I'll get an (but not the best) upper bound?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Great, thanks! One last thing -- you mentioned in your 3rd comment on this thread that "it's a lot of effort". Were you referring to the process of figuring out exactly where $\mid f(x) - \text{P}_5(x)\mid$ takes its maximum value?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to.